# Can I get a point along an SVG path without rendering it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, path

Is it possible to use browsers' built in SVG API's to compute a point along an SVG path using just the path's 'd' attribute? I'm working in React and would like to prevent staggered render cycles, as a child element needs to update any time the path's midpoint changes but has to wait for the path to render for that point to be computed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it works without rendering the path...

```js
var p = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path")

p.setAttribute("d", "M0,0L100,100")
var r = p.getPointAtLength(10)
document.write("x=" + r.x + ", y=" + r.y)
```

Comment: Yeah I like this. Good browser support and just gets garbage collected when you're done with it. Thanks!